# How Nested Components Works in Stencil?

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

I found These Snippets in Stencil's Official Docs.

I am not able to understand how **my-embedded-component** is accessible in **my-parent-component** **without providing the path of child component**. Can anyone help me understand this concept?

**Child Component**

```
import { Component, Prop } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-embedded-component'
})
export class MyEmbeddedComponent {
  @Prop() color: string = 'blue';

  render() {
    return (
    <div>My favorite color is {this.color}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
import { Component } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-parent-component'
})
export class MyParentComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <my-embedded-component color="red"></my-embedded-component>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no path. The relationship is created because the elements are nested in the HTML source.

In plain HTML the following structure, a paragraph inside a div, creates a parent/child relationship in the DOM:

```
<div>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

You are doing the same thing by using `my-embedded-component` inside the template of `MyParentComponent`. Before the parent component is rendered on the page, the initial HTML source is something like:

```
<my-parent-component>
    <div>
        <my-embedded-component color="red"></my-embedded-component>
    </div>
</my-parent-component>
```

This is then compiled to apply the behaviors described in the respective components.

The `tag` property in the `@Component` decorator defines the name of the custom tag you use in the HTML.

When the Angular compiler reads your initial HTML source code it looks for directives (tags, attributes, etc.) that have to be transformed. When those directives are nested, it creates in implicit relationship: the parent may use some of the children's properties or vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still not sure how properties will be accessible.

Comment: Look into the `@input` and `@output` decorators in the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)